# Restart currently running terminal command in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a one-click solution to stop the currently running command in the terminal and run it again?

Currently, I have to go to terminal -> `ctrl+c` to halt execution -> run the command again.

Suppose `npm run dev` is running; then it should stop and run it again after hitting some shortcut. If the single command is not possible, then I can also batch multiple commands in a single shortcut using [Commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands) extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this combination of commands - I don't know the extension syntax you use:

```
{
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "\u0003Y\u000D"   // you may not need the 'Y'
       // I also have "text": "\u001b[5c"   // Ctrl+C in my notes
  }  
},

{
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {"text": "\u001b[A\u000D"},   // uparrow and enter
}
```

Comment: It worked! I didn't need `Y`

Answer (score 0):

@Mark answer helped and if someone's using [commands](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.commands) extension, you can batch these commands into one:

settings.json:

```json
"commands.commands": {
    "Restart Terminal": {
      "sequence": [
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": {
            "text": "\u0003\u000D" // you may not need the 'Y'
            // I also have "text": "\u001b[5c"   // Ctrl+C in my notes
          }
        },
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
          "args": { "text": "\u001b[A\u000D" } // uparrow and enter
        }
      ],
      "icon": "debug-restart",
      "statusBar": {
        "alignment": "left",
        "text": "RestartTerminal",
        "priority": -4
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]